# converting normal space to tab space in linux command line

Tags: shell, command-line

I have a `text file` and this small example is one of the lines out of thousands:

```
chr1 16786571 16786572 ENST00000443980.2 0 + 16767256 16785491 0 7 118,101,105,82,109,178,1236, 0,2896,7134,7324,8357,11102,18106,
```

the space between different items is normal space. how can I replace this normal space with tab space in `linux` `command line(shell)`. in fact the results should be like the following.

```
chr1    16786571    16786572    ENST00000443980.2   0   +   16767256    16785491    0   7   118,101,105,82,109,178,1236,    0,2896,7134,7324,8357,11102,18106,
```

Comment: You can use: `tr ' ' '\t' < file`

Answer (score 1):

You mean tab/`\t`?

With sed:
`sed 's/ /\t/g' your_text_file.txt > modified_copy.txt`

With awk:
`awk -v OFS="\t" '$1=$1' your_text_file.txt`